# C# shorten datatable function

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

Using MS Visual Studio 2012 Express, Using C#.NET 4.0.

Hi guys, This I believe is a simple one.

I've been rushing a program at the request of my boss, But now it turns out that I have a lot more free time on it.

So I'm going through the code trying to make it more compact, cleaner etc.

I have this one function.....

```
public void RunMonth()
{
    //** top 10 listings*********************//            
    SetTxtBox1(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ==== END OF MONTH REPORTS starting.........\r\n");
    SetTxtBox1(" **************************************************************************************\r\n");
    try
    {
        VRMtableDESC = querys.TopVRM("DESC");
        SetTxtBox1(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ==== VRM Top has been loaded\r\n");
    }
    catch
    {
        SetTxtBox1(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ==== VRM Top has FAILED\r\n");
    }
}
```

"VRMtableDESC" is a datatable, one of around 18 datatables. for each datatable this try statement is run.

Now as you can tell this currently is repeated 18 times for every table.
instead i would like to loop into the tables instead and fill them with there data.

is there a way to do this? i would need some sort of collection for the datatables and the query.function calls too as far as I'm aware.

So far i have hit a blank so im hoping there is something im missing.

Thanks in Advance

::::UPDATE::::
Ok so I have this set up so far....

```
 foreach (DataTable tbl in MyDataSet.Tables)
 {
     tbl.TableName.Equals(querys.TopVRM(""));
 }
```

the equals method needs to be dynamic in its method selection too.... any ideas?

::UPDATE(31/10/12)::

Hi again, Im getting an error, the common error " object not sent to instance of object"

it apears on the merge in the foreach loop.

I have debugged my query call and looks fine.

```
 var tables = new SortedDictionary<string, Func<DataTable>>()
        {
            {"VRMtableDESC",  () => querys.TopVRM("DESC")},
            {"VRMtableASC",   () => querys.BotVRM("ASC")},
            {"SpectableDESC", () => querys.TopSpec("DESC")},
            {"SpectableASC",  () => querys.botSpec("ASC")},
            {"ParttableDESC", () => querys.TopPart("DESC")},
            {"ParttableASC", () => querys.BotPart("ASC")},
            {"MantableDESC",  () => querys.TopManual("DESC")},
            {"MantableASC",   () => querys.BotMan("ASC")}, //why is this first to run?????
            {"UsersLockedTbl",() => querys.UserLocked()},
            {"NewUsersTbl",   () => querys.NewUsers()},

            {"VRMtotaltblTOP",   () => querys.VRMtotalTOP("")},
            {"PARTtotaltblTOP",  () => querys.PARTtotalTOP("")},
            {"SPECtotaltblTOP",  () => querys.SPECtotalTOP("")},
            {"MANtotaltblTOP",   () => querys.MANtotalTOP("")},
            {"VRMtotaltblBOT",   () => querys.VRMtotalBOT("")},
            {"PARTtotaltblBOT",  () => querys.PARTtotalBOT("")},
            {"SPECtotaltblBOT",  () => querys.SPECtotalBOT("")},
            {"MANtotaltblBOT",   () => querys.MANtotalBOT("")},
        };

        foreach(var kvp in tables)
        {
            try
            {
                MyDataSet.Tables[kvp.Key].Merge(kvp.Value());//error occurs here
                SetTxtBox1(String.Format("{0} ==== {1} has been Loaded\r\n", DateTime.Now.ToString(), kvp.Key));
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                SetTxtBox1(String.Format("{0} ==== {1} has FAILED\r\n", DateTime.Now.ToString(), kvp.Key));
                MessageBox.Show("error:::" + e);
            }
        }
        AutoRunApp();
```

any help would be great.

UPDATE::

heres my query call from the "bunchofquerys" class

```
 public DataTable BotMan(string order)
    {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnString32);
            SqlCommand vrm = new SqlCommand();
            //BindingSource bindme = new BindingSource();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(vrm);
           // DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet();
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
            try
            {
            vrm.Connection = conn;
            vrm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (order.Equals("DESC"))
            {
                vrm.CommandText = "dbo.TopManual";
            }
            vrm.CommandText = "dbo.BotManual";
            vrm.CommandTimeout = 360;

            vrm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBy", order);
            adapt1.Fill(table1);
            return table1;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("eeror::zomg:::  " + e);

        }
        return table1;
    }
```

Comment: The natural collection for a DataTable is the DataSet. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeskbwf7.aspx

Comment: indeed I have a dataset and i have add the blank tables to it.But not sure how to add the querys to each table inside the dataset.

Comment: currently i have a foreach(datatable tbl in myDataSet.tables) but its the code context that i need to itterate through that im not sure on, syntax etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you already have a `DataSet`. An easy way to fill all the tables is to use [`Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx).

In this example, I create a mapping between the table names (the name of the table in the `DataSet`), and the corresponding query function (assuming that they return a `DataTable` with a similar schema, and your `DataSet` is named `ds`).

The `Key` is used to query the appropriate `DataTable` from the `DataSet`, and then the `Merge` method is used to "fill" the `DataTable`.

```
var tables = new SortedDictionary<string, Func<DataTable>>() //or use List of Tuples... 
{
    {"VRM_TOP",    () => querys.TopVRM("DESC")},
    {"FooBar_TOP", () => querys.FooBar("DESC")},
    {"Something",  () => querys.Something("ASC")},
};

foreach(var kvp in tables)
    ds.Tables[kvp.Key].Merge(kvp.Value());
```

You could do it the other way round and iterate over each table in you `DataSet` and get the appropriate loader function via the table's `TableName`.

Your `try/catch` block can now easily be added to the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach(var kvp in tables)
{
    try
    {
        ds.Tables[kvp.Key].Merge(kvp.Value());
        SetTxtBox1(String.Format("{0} ==== {1} has ben loaded\r\n", DateTime.Now, kvp.Key));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: ive used your solution, an error is occurring that says an entery with the same key already exists, any ideas?

Comment: You probably added a key twice to the dictionary.

Comment: Hi, yeh it was.  I do however have a new Problem, I will update my question to show what is going on.

Comment: I *guess* one of your methods of the `querys` object is returning `null` instead of a `DataTable` (but you should know *what exactly* is `null`). You should be able to figure out which one it is using the debugger and examining `kvp.Key`.

Comment: well ive ran my query on sql manager, works fine. runs the method in my program with no errors, some strange reason the table has no values in. still no error, error occurs on merge.  kvp.key  says "mantableasc"  kvp.value says " kvp.Value = {Method = {System.Data.DataTable <RunMonth>b__8()}}"

Comment: when i say table has no values, when my datatable is filled there are no values in it, on sql there are values. sorry for confusion

Comment: So, does `querys.BotMan("ASC")` actually return a `DataTable`? Or maybe `MyDataSet` is `null`?

Comment: yes datset is saying null, just noticed...hmmm any ideas why or would you like to see the query method?

Comment: You obviously have to create an instance of your `DataSet`-class, then.

Comment: my dataset is instantiated already globaly.  my querys are in a class called bunchofquerys that is also instantiated.  could you please explain what you mean by the dataset class?

Comment: for some reason its also only running the "man or manual" querys if i comment them out it errors. i then re-run it and now it is tryin only a different one called users